# Métodos lower() e strip()

Tags: python-3.x

```
print ("Escreva uma frase toda em maiúscula e sem espaços em branco")

frase = input("Escreva uma frase: ")
print (frase.lower())
print (frase.strip())
```

Resultado:

```
Escreva uma frase toda em maiúscula e sem espaços em branco
Escreva uma frase: oi tudo bem?
oi tudo bem?
oi tudo bem?
```

Por que não funciona?

Comment: O que não está funcionando?

Comment: print (frase.lower())
    print (frase.strip())

Eu não deveria ter uma frase toda em maiúscula e outra sem espaços?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ora bem, para a frase toda em maiusculas seria:

```
frase.upper()
```

Para a frase sem espaços:

```
frase.replace(' ', '')
```

Explicação:

Quanto às letras que querias em maiuscula estavas a usar o metodo oposto, estavas a usar o metodo que as muta para minusculas.

E quanto a retirar os espaços, o método `strip()` apenas os retira no início e final da string.